# Entityqueue - Get field values from the queue

Tags: views, entities, blocks

First off, i'm very new to Drupal. Kindly help me and forgive if im being a noob.

Im using the module - **Entityqueue** https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue

Im created a view block for a entity queue that gets specific blog articles.

The problem im facing is that, this view only gets the blog title, and not the other custom fields within each blog.

Is there anyway to get the custom fields also ?

Thank you for your support.

EDIT: Please see below for screnshot of what i've done.

**Entityqueue**
[image]

**View Block**
[image]

If i select fields below, it doesn't get the custom field that are in the blog article.
[image]

Comment: "The blog title"-- Do you mean the blog post title or the title of the blog itself?  You probably need to add the other fields in the View block under **Content**, but it's difficult to say without seeing your view configuration.  Can you post a screenshot of the Views administration page for your block?

Comment: @PatrickKenny Hello, thanks for your reply. I meant the blog post title. I've added the screenshot of my view for your kind reference.

Comment: I now understand that it can done using "Relationships" in the advanced settings of view block above, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

After you create the entity queue, go to view and create/edit a view block.

Select **Relationship** as **Content queue**, now you can get the fields in the fields section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The answer provided by @Thowzif is correct. But people who are looking for the exact steps with screenshots, can use this [article](https://opensenselabs.com/blog/tech/create-list-random-items-drupal-8).